# Asynchronous method testing in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following event handler - which uses Dispatcher.BeginInvoke which I believe is different to another stack overflow question similar on BeginInvoke:

```
private void source_load_complete()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( new NotificationDelegate( source_load_complete_ui ), null );
    }
```

and then:

```
private void source_load_complete_ui()
    {
        m_image.Image = m_bmp.CreateBitmap();
        m_image.UpdateImage( null );
        m_image.LoadComplete = true;
        raise_property_changed( "CurrentImage" );
    }
```

And to test this, the following test method:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ImageVM_SourceLoadTests()
    {
        ImageViewModel ivm = new ImageViewModel();
        List<string> eventList = new List<string>();

        ivm.PropertyChanged += delegate( object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e )
        {
            eventList.Add( e.PropertyName );
        };

        // check the model is set up correctly so the event in the constructor works
        CustomImage model = ivm.ImageModel as CustomImage;
        WriteableBitmap bmp = model.Image;

        if( model.ImageSource.LoadComplete != null )
        {
// fire off the event we want to test is handled correctly
            model.ImageSource.LoadComplete();
        }

        Assert.IsTrue( model.LoadComplete == true);
        Assert.IsTrue( model.Image == bmp );
        Assert.IsTrue( eventList.Count == 1 );
    }
```

Clearly this will not work, as the source_load_complete_ui method is invoked asyncronously. However I can't figure out after searching around how best to test this and wait for the asynchronous method to be called?

EDIT:
I didn't mention that this class inherits Dispatcher object, and therefore the BeginInvoke is not related to the answer given:

```
public class ImageViewModel : DispatcherObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Hence not being a duplicate suggested

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Unit Test BeginInvoke on an Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885993/how-to-unit-test-begininvoke-on-an-action)

Comment: I'll have a closer look at it, but it is talking about a different BeginInvoke method I believe

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured this answer is actually related to this answer [Using the WPF Dispatcher in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106881/using-the-wpf-dispatcher-in-unit-tests)

Using a dispatcher helper util described in this answer, you can force it to process the queue and use this in the unit test.

```
public static class DispatcherUtil
{

[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
public static void DoEvents()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}

private static object ExitFrame(object frame)
{
    ((DispatcherFrame)frame).Continue = false;
    return null;
}
}
```